# openui5 list bound to a model with different list item types

Tags: sapui5

I have a sap.m.List in openui5 which is bound to a JSON model.

The list should contain normal list items (such as the type sap.m.StandardListItem), but there should also be separator once every year through the list item type sap.m.GroupHeaderListItem.
[Example JSBin with such a list](http://output.jsbin.com/rozapa)

Is it possible to achieve this when the data is bound using bindAggregation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, should be perfectly possible, have a look at the example at https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListGrouping/code

Of course you need to sort your aggregation to the field you need to group on, and then you can supply a `groupHeaderFactory` to your items aggregation:

```
<List items="{
  path: '/ProductCollection',
  sorter: {
    path: 'SupplierName',
    descending: false,
    group: true
  },
  groupHeaderFactory: '.getGroupHeader'
}">
```

and the called factory function then returns a `GroupHeaderListItem` based on a certain value for your data:

```
getGroupHeader: function (oGroup){
    return new sap.m.GroupHeaderListItem( {
        title: oGroup.key,
        upperCase: false
    });
}
```